# How to save queries executed by Athena in LogsGroup CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-athena

I want to save the requests executed by Athena in a LogsGroup of the CloudWatch service.

In CloudWatch, I created this rule:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.athena"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Athena Query State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "currentState": [
      "QUEUED",
      "RUNNING",
      "SUCCEEDED",
      "FAILED",
      "CANCELLED"
    ]
  }
}
```

And, I attached the rule to a CloudWatch LogsGroup like this:

[LogsGroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwlqB.png)

I managed to register logs in CloudWatch -> Log groups -> /aws/events/TestAthena but I don't have the information I want:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "a8bad43b-1b9a-da7e-c004-f3c920e1bddd",
    "detail-type": "Athena Query State Change",
    "source": "aws.athena",
    "account": "<account_id>",
    "time": "2021-08-23T15:54:13Z",
    "region": "eu-west-3",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "currentState": "RUNNING",
        "previousState": "QUEUED",
        "queryExecutionId": "b0fe7373-676d-43d5-b866-19d701c9dc56",
        "sequenceNumber": "2",
        "statementType": "DML",
        "versionId": "0",
        "workgroupName": "dev-Connect-CardBulk"
    }
}
```

I wish to have :

- The request executed
- The time the request was executed
- The user who executed the request

It is possible to have this with CloudWatch ?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: For these details you should be looking at cloudtrail logs.

Comment: Out of the box, you can have QueryPlanningTime, QueryQueuetime etc. metrics. Nonetheless, you need Cloudtrail to track who executed. Refer to these links: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/query-metrics-viewing.html#athena-cloudwatch-metrics-table & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1V_lhkdKCg

Comment: Thank's a lot @Ash, i'll check Cloudtrail and you'r docs

Comment: Thank's a lot @PrabhakarReddy

Comment: This topic is solved :)

Can you please someone post answer for validate ? @Ash ?

Comment: Glad to hear @Mitsukk, will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, you can have QueryPlanningTime, QueryQueuetime etc. metrics.
Nonetheless, you need Cloudtrail to track who executed.

Refer to these links:

[List of CloudWatch Metrics and Dimensions for Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/query-metrics-viewing.html#athena-cloudwatch-metrics-table)

[Monitoring Amazon Athena Queries using Amazon CloudWatch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1V_lhkdKCg)